# Should I allow query parameters and seperate data if not needed?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, query-string, http-method

I am having some thoughts of how to design my server in node js. I had some thoughts about allowing or not the client to send data to the server using query parameters `my.site.com?data=some data by the client` or via the body when using the POST method `{data:'some data by the client'}`.
I was questioning:

1) Is there a proper way to design my server by some constraints?
    I am thinking about data come to the server without needed so why accepting that is a good practice?

2) If I should not allow the client to send query or body data when not needed what HTTP status should I return (404 or 400)?

**EXAMPLE**

I have an URI path for a GET method and I expect the path alone like this

`http://my.site.com/something`

or like this

`http://my.site.com/something?search=I search for anything`

when the user send me this GET URL:

`http://my.site.com/something?here=not something that is useful to the server`

Should I send a 400 HTTP status for BAD REQUEST or 404 for NOT FOUND or respond with 200 OK? And if OK why should I allow other queries if the server is not using them?

Same question applies for POST method if I need for example

`{uname:'username',pwd:'password'}` why should I allow the user to send me for example

`{uname:'username',pwd:'password',some:'other data here'}`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user sends extra url parameters, you should simply ignore it. This is what most servers do. For example, a Google search for `https://www.google.com/#q=ant&coolness=true` returns the exact same thing as `https://www.google.com/#q=ant` because `coolness` is not a url parameter keyword used by Google.

The same goes for extra POST parameters, although if you have a form or website, you should probably make sure the user only sends whatever data is necessary.